# Yii2 Set start day in Date picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, yii2

I am using the date picker widget in my project.No I want to set my start day of the week from monday to sunday.I tried multiple things.unfortunately I cant succeed.Can anyone help me...
I am sharing my code here.

```
<?= $form->field($model,'apartment_year_build')->widget(DatePicker::className(),[ 'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM', 'clientOptions' => [
                        'changeMonth' => true,
                        'yearRange' => '1989:2099',
                        'changeYear' => true,
                        'firstday'=>1,
                        // 'showOn' => 'button',
                        // 'buttonImage' => 'images/calendar.gif',
                        // 'buttonImageOnly' => true,
                        // 'buttonText' => 'Select date'

                    ],'options'=>['class'=>'form-control']]) ?>
```

Comment: Which one exactly you are using? Many different DatePicker extensions exist. It's better to add a link or full namespace.

Comment: yii\jui\DatePicker; this is the datepicker I am using...

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the code 'firstDay'=>1 with 'firstDay=>'1'

Answer (score 0):

Use `'dateFormat'` inside `clientOptions`

```
<?= $form->field($model,'apartment_year_build')->widget(DatePicker::className(),[ 'clientOptions' => [
                            'changeMonth' => true,
                            'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM', 
                            'yearRange' => '1989:2099',
                            'changeYear' => true,
                            'firstday'=>'1',
                            // 'showOn' => 'button',
                            // 'buttonImage' => 'images/calendar.gif',
                            // 'buttonImageOnly' => true,
                            // 'buttonText' => 'Select date'

                        ],'options'=>['class'=>'form-control']]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`firstDay` set the first day of the week. Default is Sunday (0), so delete the property or set it to 0.

```
<?= $form->field($model,'apartment_year_build')->widget(DatePicker::className(),[ 'dateFormat' => 'yyyy-MM', 'clientOptions' => [
                        'changeMonth' => true,
                        'yearRange' => '1989:2099',
                        'changeYear' => true,
                        // 'showOn' => 'button',
                        // 'buttonImage' => 'images/calendar.gif',
                        // 'buttonImageOnly' => true,
                        // 'buttonText' => 'Select date'

                    ],'options'=>['class'=>'form-control']]) ?>
```

**Docs**: https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/